# How do I count data in a text file using c# with visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Looking  for assistance with sample code to Sum the values of a column within a text file using C# in Visual studio

Say the text file has the following lines

Bread,2(Price),3(Quantity)
Cheese,5,1
Milk,1,2
Weetbix,1,5

This is what i got so far but no idea how to do it, its a .txt file

```
public class GroceryProgram
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // main consists of a single call to the grocery class
        var grocery = new InvoiceItem();
       // grocery.readFile();
        grocery.writeFile();
    }

    public class InvoiceItem
    {   //label all properties
        public static List<string> items = new List<string>();

        public string type { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
        public double quantity { get; set; }
        public double weight { get; set; }

        public InvoiceItem()
        {
        }
        public InvoiceItem(string n, double p) //declaring the main input to be a string name of grocery n followed by a double as p
        {
            name = n;
            price = p;
        }
        public List<string> readFile()
        {
            string line = "";
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("groceries.txt"); //variable reader to read file
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) //reader reads each line while the lines is not blank, line is assigned value of reader
            {
                line = line.Trim();     //gets rid of any spaces on each iteration within the line

                if (line.Length > 0) //during  each line the below actions are performed
                {
                    string[] splitArray = line.Split(new char[] { ',' });  //creates a array called splitArray which splits each line into an array and a new char

                    type = splitArray[0]; // type is assigned for each line at position [0] on
                    name = splitArray[1]; //name is assigned at position [1]

                    //<<<-------food cost calculation methods initialized-------->>>>
                    RegularItem purchasedItem = new RegularItem(splitArray); //purchased Item is the each line to be printed
                    FreshItem freshItem = new FreshItem(splitArray);

                    double regCost = purchasedItem.getRegularCost();  //regCost will multiply array at position [2] with [3]
                    double freshCost = freshItem.getFreshItemCost();

                    string regArr = string.Join(",", line, "Cost: ", regCost);
                    string freshArr = string.Join(",", line, "Cost: ", freshCost);

                    if (type == "regular")
                    {
                        // items.InsertRange(4, (arrayList)); //first write a line in the list with the each line written
                        items.Add(regArr);
                        //items.Add(Convert.ToString(newArray));
                        //items.Add("RegularItemCost:");
                        //items.Add(Convert.ToString(regCost));  //next add the regCost method to write a line with the cost of that item
                    }
                    else if (type == "fresh")
                    {
                        items.Add(freshArr);
                        //items.Add(Convert.ToString(freshItem)); //first write a line in the list with the each line written
                        //items.Add("FreshItemCost:");
                        //items.Add(Convert.ToString(freshCost));  //next add the fresh method to write another line with the cost of that item
                    }

                }


            }

            return items;
        }

        public int sumPrice(string filepath)
        {
            using (StreamReader readAgain = new StreamReader("groceries.txt"))
            {
                int i = 0;
                while (readAgain.ReadLine() != null) { i++; }
                return i;
            }
        }


        // WRITE FILE
        public void writeFile() //maybe add file name inside paranthesis <<+=========MAIN EXECUTOR
        {
            //Begin writing
            List<string> lines = readFile();

            string[] first = { "Grocery for you", Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now) };
            StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("c:\\MicrosoftVisual\\invoice.txt");  //sets to use variable file to write to location

            foreach (string firstLine in first)
            {
                file.WriteLine(firstLine);   //use file to write the header grocery for you first
            }
            //begin writing all items into the file
            foreach (string newLine in lines)
            {
                file.WriteLine(newLine);   //use file to write all lines
                Console.WriteLine(newLine);
            }

            //  file.WriteLine(items[2].Sum); //trying to get total price by adding position 2 for total weight for later
            //file.WriteLine(items[3].Sum); //trying to get total quantity/weight
            file.Flush();
        }


        public class RegularItem : InvoiceItem //inheriting properties from class GroceryItem
        {

            private string[] splitArray;

            public RegularItem()
            {
            }

            public RegularItem(string[] splitArray) //enables constructor for RegularItem to split into array
            {
                this.type = splitArray[0];
                this.name = splitArray[1];
                this.price = double.Parse(splitArray[2]); //each line at position 4 is a double
               this.quantity = double.Parse(splitArray[3]); //each line at position 3 is parsed to an integer
            }

            public double getRegularCost() //method from cost of regular
            {
                return this.price * this.quantity * 1.1; //workout out cost  for purchases including GST
            }
        }
        public class FreshItem : InvoiceItem    //Inheriting properties from class Purchased Item
        {
            public double weight;
            private string[] splitArray;

            public FreshItem()
            {
                this.type = splitArray[0];
                this.name = splitArray[1];
                this.price = double.Parse(splitArray[2]); //each line at position 4 is a double
                this.weight = double.Parse(splitArray[3]); //each line at position 3 is parsed to an integer

            }
            public FreshItem(string[] splitArray) //enables constructor for RegularItem to split into array
            {
                this.type = splitArray[0];
                this.name = splitArray[1];
                this.price = double.Parse(splitArray[2]); //each line at position 4 is a double
                this.weight = double.Parse(splitArray[3]); //each line at position 3 is parsed to an integer
            }
            public double getFreshItemCost() //method to get cost of fresh item
            {
                return this.price * this.weight; //workout cost of the fresh item excluding GST
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I need to find out how to sum all the values in the price column to write to a new file, and sum the value on the quantity column to write to the file too.
I know how to iterate through each line but how do we add the position of each column together 0.O

Was thinking maybe something like a foreach might work, sorry about the many questions guys

Comment: Looks like CSV file. Parse it and count.

Comment: Can you show what you tried so far. How are reading the data into the program? Is this a console app etc?

Comment: look like a Json, deserialise the file to a List<CustomObject> sum the property you need, create the new file with the result. That's almost 4-5 lines of code when you remove the object definition and mapping.

Comment: You way want to look at [CSV Helper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

Comment: A simple LinQ group by will be enought to update the cart and compute price per item/ total new quantity etc.

Comment: Quantity and Weight are both double, stored in the same column, Used the same way in the Cost math. Are they really distinct? They are just simple value. The fact that quantity is either countable things or weight, should be captured by an other property. This way every it could have a weight, a name, a price and based on this property(enum) you could choose the math. and still have the total weight of the cart.

Comment: while I'm here, You have a lot of redundant comment. Your property and Method have correct name you can throw all the comment explaining that `GetSomethingCost` will get me the cost of Something. And comment on the line before. At the end of the line, people will have to scroll every time to see if code matches the comment. At the 2nd one I had to ignore the comment.

Comment: I will recommend reading the 4 1rst chapters of Clean Code  by R Martin. Read it like a side book without taking note just to get the general idea somewhere in your mind. As it take many re lecture to fully understand some of the point.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to read out the file line by line. Try something like this:

```
    decimal totalPrice = 0;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("your file fullpath");
    while(!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        decimal price = 0;
        decimal.TryParse(reader.ReadLine().Split(',')[1], out price);

        totalPrice += price;
    }
    reader.Close();
```